# Replace a repeating pattern using regex

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I want to replace all non quoted array keys in my source code :

```
$array[keyValue]
```

with quoted array keys:

```
$array['keyValue']
```

For single dimension arrays this regexp allows me to do this :

```
preg_replace('/\$([a-z-_0-9]+)(\[([a-z][a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)\])+/', '\$$1['$3']', $input_lines);
```

test : https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/pXc

Note all my keys start with a lower case letter.

My problem comes when I have multi dimension arrays and I want to change:

```
$array[keyValue1][keyValue2]
```

to :

```
$array['keyValue1']['keyValue2']
```

or even

```
$array[keyValue1]...[keyValueN]
```

to

```
$array['keyValue1']...['keyValueN']
```

for larger dimension-ed arrays.  Any attempt I make to match the pattern multiple times ends up matching between the first opening bracket `[` and the last one `]` as one match.

Edit: Reason for doing this is to avoid errors and notices like this

```
E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Use of undefined constant key - assumed 'key' -- at line 2
```

in my logs

Comment: do you understand that technically `$array[keyValue1]` should never exist? the key should be a string. So you want a sting to quote itself? so next time in your code you will need to address element like `$array['\'keyValue1\'']`?  https://ideone.com/uFXrqV

Comment: I just wonder who upvoted this weird question? Any cooments why that is interesting for you guys?

Comment: Wasn't me. I just checked the code for fun. Saw two warnings and got `array (size=1)
  'myKey' => 
    array (size=1)
      'myValue' => int 0`

on `var_dump(array(myKey => array(myValue => 0)));`

Comment: @Alex What made you think it is *weird*?

Comment: @revo check my 1st comment. I even spent some time to explain with example - please follow the link in comment

Comment: @Alex OP talks about all *unquoted keys* so I could think of some legacy codes that weren't well written and they are going through a refactoring process. Also `$array[keyValue1]` could exist but if `keyValue1` is a predefined constant then PHP doesn't complain. See what [happens here](https://3v4l.org/MRqAr) if we comment out `define(...`.

Comment: @revo good guess. But is it refactoring? Do we have any proof? I feel that question is weird. And I am fine if you do not. I see your point. And I understand that if we would only focus on regex part of question it is interesting. But since that is about transforming php code. Hmmm... I still have that feelings.

Comment: @revo You're right about legacy code.  Code was written without quoting keys but our logs are now filling with notices and also slowing down the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note: take care of predefined constants. This doesn't and can't ignore them.*

You are in need of a continuous match using `\G`. Use `preg_replace` with the following regex:

```
(\$\w+\[|\G(?!\A)\[)([^]['"]+)\]
```

and put the following string as the substitution string:

```
$1'$2']
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/EWrAH8/1)

PHP code:

```
preg_replace('~(\$\w+\[|\G(?!\A)\[)([^][\'"]+)\]~', '$1\'$2\']', $str);
```

Regex break down:

- `(` Start of capturing group #1

  - `\$\w+\[` Match a `$` then some word characters then an opening bracket
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!\A)` Start match from where previous match ends
  - `\[` Match an opening bracket
- `)` End of capturing group #1
- `(` Start of capturing group #2

  - `[^]['"]+` Match anything but `[`, `]`, `'` and `"`
- `)` End of capturing group #2
- `\]` Match a closing bracket

Comment: Pre defined constants are ALL in capitals... Thankfully :-)    So this should not be an issue.  I'm getting "undefined constant, assuming its a key" notices in the logs...

Comment: Then to exclude those constants (if it is possible for them to be used as a key) use `(\$\w+\[|\G(?!\A)\[)(?![A-Z][A-Z\d_]*\])([^]['"]+)\]`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/EWrAH8/2

Comment: what about `$array[$keyValue1][$keyValue2]`? https://regex101.com/r/EWrAH8/3 is it designed to quote variables ;-)

Comment: @Alex No it doesn't work with variables and it can't easily. Up to now OP talks about some constants / strings and not variables. So it's fine for this answer to exist.